# PineScript 'ta.lowest' and 'ta.highest' shows wrong value when in 'if' condition

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, tradingview-api

I have the following PineScript to check if the RSI value of 2 or more consecutive candles lie within range specified in the `if` condition

```
//@version=5
indicator("RSICondition", overlay=true, max_bars_back = 20)

RSI = ta.rsi(close, 14)

varip int ToPlot = 0                            //0 means nothing to plot, 1 means to plot RED-BOX
varip int left = 0                              //Pointer for the left edge of the box
varip float highestHigh = na                    //Declaring Global Variable
varip float lowestLow = na                      //Declaring Global Variable

if (RSI >= 58 and RSI <= 62)
    left := left + 1
    if (left > 1)                               //If we have consecutive candles within 58 & 62, eg. lets take 3 consecutive candles
        highestHigh := ta.highest(high, left)   //Calculating the Highest High from the 3 candles
        lowestLow := ta.lowest(low, left)       //Calculating the Lowest Low from the 3 candles
        ToPlot := 1                             //Specifying RED color box to plot

else
    if (ToPlot == 1)                            //When the candle after 3 consecutive candles within specified range comes, time to plot RED box for those 3 candles
        box.new(bar_index[left], highestHigh, bar_index[1], lowestLow, border_color=color.red, bgcolor=color.new(color.red, 80))
    ToPlot := 0                                 //Reset ToPlot to 0 after plotting specifying there is nothing to plot now
    left := 0                                   //Reset the pointer after box plotted
```

The compiler shows the following warnings for both `ta.lowest` and `ta.highest` : `The function '<function_name>' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from this scope` and also the boxes created show the incorrect values for the `highestHigh` and `lowestLow` variables since they are specified for top and bottom edge of the box respectively.

I could specify these functions outside the `if` statement but sometimes the value of `left` variable becomes 0 as well where there error throws `length for ta.highest and ta.lowest cannot be 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must evaluate `ta.highest()` outside of an if conditional.

```
highestHighTmp = ta.highest(high, math.max(1, left)) // should "left" be 0 you don't use it anyway
lowestLowTmp = ta.lowest(low, math.max(1, left))
if (RSI >= 58 and RSI <= 62)
    left := left + 1
    if (left > 1)
        highestHigh := highestHighTmp
        lowestLow := lowestLowTmp
        ToPlot := 1                     
...
```

Comment: This might work, but the issue now is even when 'left = 4', the variable 'highestHighTmp' gets the value where 'left = 1'. It does not take left = 4. I verified the value of 'left' by plotting it separately.           If I manually put '4' instead of the 'left' variable, I get the correct answer, but not when 'left' variable is put there.           I also tried removing the 'math.max' function and placing the 'left' variable directly, but no luck.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. 2 parts of my solution for the warning issued by tv: 1. extract ta.highest() outside of if 2. make sure to not break the script with length == 0. Both parts are correct and work as intended, per se. Check it simply by "indicator("RSICondition", overlay=true, max_bars_back = 20)
plot(ta.highest(high, math.max(1, 4)))" This returns you always the highest value in the last 4 bars. I assume you have a different problem, like setting "left" dynamically but that issue has nothing to do with ta.highest() anymore.

Comment: What I mean is, even when the value of 'left' is 4, the variables highestHighTmp and lowestLowTmp are getting the value as if left is equal to 1, although the value of left comes correct at other areas, just the issue is where ta.highest and ta.lowest are used.